# Monitoring remote filesystem with Monit

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

Does anyone have an example or an idea of how to monitor remote filesystems? I can monitor my local host fine, not sure of the correct syntax to monitor remote system or even if this is possible.

This is what I have for a local check:

```
check filesystem apps with path /dev/mapper/root_vg-apps
    if space usage > 90% then alert
```

Comment: You need to install monit on all of your hosts to monitor them. Exactly the same way you would do it on localhost, with the configuration as you posted it. (there is no way at all to check filesystems from remote, other solution use clients and monit is a client instance itself)

Answer (score 2):

A Monit check can itself be a shell script. So you could try writing a script that ssh's into your remote box and checks disk space levels. If free space is below 10% your script should be written to exit with a non-zero return code which Monit will detect.

Comment: An example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

1. add monitoring machine ssh keys to remote machine`s ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
2. login from monitoring machine via 'ssh user@checking-machine'
3. logout from checked-machine via 'exit' command
4. mount remote machine filesystem into monitoring machine folder
   for example:

   `sshfs -o ro root@checking-machine:/ /root/remote_fs/checking/`
5. add monitoring config to monit file /etc/monit.d/remote-fs.conf

> ```
> check device CHECKING-FS with path /root/remote_fs/cheking
> if space usage > 90% then alert
> ```

6. service monit restart

Answer (score -3):

You can try Nagios which woks in a Server-Client model

You can monitoring anything in remote host.

Try this URL to see how to install and configure it....

http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-nagios-in-centos-6-4-rhel-6-4/

Comment: The answer is in no way related to the question.

Comment: Because the question was how to monitor filesystems with MONIT. Your answer does not relate to this.